# iPad doesn't ask for home sharing password

Tags: ipad, itunes, home-sharing

I have set up homes sharing on both my iPad and macbook's iTunes. Originally I did not set a password and it worked. Now I have set a password in iTunes preferences and when accessing my shared library on the iPad the content from library is displayed without me having to enter the password.

I have tried removing my apple ID from the settings app and restarting iTunes as well as the iPod and video apps on my iPad. Still I can access my content without entering a password.

So why am I able to access my content without the password and how do I fix it, so that the password is required?

Comment: OK - you've got a great statement - what exactly do you want to do? What question do you want answered?

Comment: I thought it would be kind of obvious that I was asking why I can access the content without the password and how to make it so the password is required, but nevertheless I have edited my question.

Comment: There's something wrong on the iPad - but did you turn off Home Sharing on the computer to force it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to just turn off Home Sharing on your computer, then two things come to mind.

If you changed the Apple ID somewhere else than the iPod settings - then that would explain things. (I've accidentally cleared the store account when I meant to change this upon going to a friend's house)

[image]

I just tested on my iPad and deleting the home share as depicted above immediately disconnected from my Home Share - I didn't need to kill iTunes on the iPad or do any re-starting - the effect was immediate as soon as I exited the settings tab.

Assuming you got the place correct, then your iPad iTunes database is a little corrupt. Sometimes syncing the iPad with a different iTunes library (music only) will delete your music and settings and allow things to work again. It's not easy to poke in the files directly on the iPad - and you may have to restore the device and set it up as new if getting a new set of iTunes data doesn't resolve it.

Lastly - you [could check troubleshooting steps with Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4557) - the express lane at the bottom is good if the steps listed don't resolve it for you. It's highly unlikely to be something on your account with them or the computer, but they will know the oddball causes if the obvious next steps don't work.

Comment: It seems I got confused between Home Sharing and sharing libaries (http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/confused_about_itunes_home_sharing/). I want to be able to access my library through my ipad but only after entering a password each time? Do iOS devices only support Home Sharing and not the older Sharing method?

Comment: Wow - I hadn't even thought of that - great catch. I just disabled home sharing and my iOS 4.3.3 devices don't see an old style sharing iTunes. I think that was only computer to computer, but can't find it documented anywhere. I do remember entering a password in the remote app to control the music, but not to actually share it independent of the main music playing on the computer.